# column specific click event in datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a dataGridView that has 2 columns called (colour & desc) and I want to have a click event that only fires on the (colour) column.

I have searched a bit on the net and seen various ways to do this via row index but nothing by column index.

Any help would be appreciated..,thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create event handler for `datagridview.CellClick` event

```
Private Sub dgv_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellClick
    Dim yourColumnIndex As Int32 = 1
    If e.ColumnIndex = yourColumnIndex Then
        'Do your staff
    End If
End Sub
```

Or if you have predefined columns then:

```
Private Sub dgv_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellClick
    If e.ColumnIndex = Me.colour.Index Then
        'Do your staff
    End If
End Sub
```